# Calculating Five-Day Expanding Average for Minute-Level Data in ClickHouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have minute-level data in ClickHouse, and I need to calculate a five-day expanding average. The challenge I'm facing is that the timestamps may not follow consecutive calendar dates. However, there is always data available for legal trading days, which are defined as starting at 9:00 PM of the previous natural day and ending at 9:00 PM of the current natural day.

For example, if I have a timestamp of March 15, 2023, at 12:18 AM, I need to find the starting point (9:00 PM) of the trading day that was five trading days ago, which would be March 8, 2023, at 9:00 PM. Even if the timestamp is March 15, 2023, at 9:19 AM, the expanding window should still go back to the trading day starting on March 8, 2023, at 9:00 PM.

I'm seeking guidance on how to efficiently implement this in ClickHouse, as the BETWEEN statement doesn't support date calculations, and ClickHouse's SQL doesn't seem to provide a direct solution for this scenario.

Is there a way to calculate a five-day expanding average for minute-level data while considering trading days that start at 9:00 PM of the previous natural day and end at 9:00 PM of the current natural day in ClickHouse? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

and below is an example of what I expect clickhosue to generte for me :

```
+---------------------+-------+------------------------+-----------------------+
|    timestamp       | value | five_day_starting_point| five_day_expanding_avg|
+---------------------+-------+------------------------+-----------------------+
| 2023-03-08 21:00:00|  10.0 | 2023-03-08 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-08 21:01:00|  12.0 | 2023-03-08 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-08 21:02:00|  14.0 | 2023-03-08 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-09 21:00:00|  15.0 | 2023-03-09 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-09 21:01:00|  14.5 | 2023-03-09 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-09 21:02:00|  16.0 | 2023-03-09 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-10 21:00:00|  18.0 | 2023-03-10 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-10 21:01:00|  20.0 | 2023-03-10 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-10 21:02:00|  22.0 | 2023-03-10 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-11 21:00:00|  23.0 | 2023-03-11 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-11 21:01:00|  24.0 | 2023-03-11 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-11 21:02:00|  25.0 | 2023-03-11 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-12 21:00:00|  26.0 | 2023-03-12 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-12 21:01:00|  27.0 | 2023-03-12 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-12 21:02:00|  28.0 | 2023-03-12 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-13 21:00:00|  29.0 | 2023-03-13 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-13 21:01:00|  30.0 | 2023-03-13 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-13 21:02:00|  31.0 | 2023-03-13 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-14 21:00:00|  32.0 | 2023-03-14 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-14 21:01:00|  33.0 | 2023-03-14 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-14 21:02:00|  34.0 | 2023-03-14 21:00:00  |           NULL        |
| 2023-03-15 21:00:00|  35.0 | 2023-03-15 21:00:00  |          18.5        |
| 2023-03-15 21:01:00|  36.0 | 2023-03-15 21:00:00  |          18.58       |
| 2023-03-15 21:02:00|  37.0 | 2023-03-15 21:00:00  |          18.67       |
+---------------------+-------+------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The `BETWEEN` does not support date calculations, but you can perform them outside of the window using a CTE (a `WITH` clause). Also, you need an `if` because going back to 9:00 is not the same calculation if it's after midnight.

Something like this maybe, where 432000 is 5 days in minutes:

```
WITH 
   if(
      toHour(toStartOfHour(timestamp)) >= 21, 
      toStartOfDay(timestamp) + toIntervalHour(21),
      (toStartOfDay(timestamp) - toIntervalDay(1)) + toIntervalHour(21)
   ) 
   AS start_of_day
SELECT
    timestamp,
    value,
    start_of_day,
    avg(value) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp ASC RANGE BETWEEN 432000 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS moving_avg
FROM arthur
ORDER BY timestamp ASC

Query id: c77b26d1-1fa0-47c5-99cb-1f9f9e7bc7c4

┌───────────timestamp─┬─value─┬────────start_of_day─┬─moving_avg─┐
│ 2023-03-08 21:00:00 │    10 │ 2023-03-08 21:00:00 │         10 │
│ 2023-03-08 21:01:00 │    12 │ 2023-03-08 21:00:00 │         11 │
│ 2023-03-08 21:02:00 │    14 │ 2023-03-08 21:00:00 │         12 │
│ 2023-03-09 20:59:00 │    15 │ 2023-03-08 21:00:00 │      12.75 │
│ 2023-03-09 21:00:00 │    15 │ 2023-03-09 21:00:00 │               13.2 │
│ 2023-03-09 21:01:00 │  14.5 │ 2023-03-09 21:00:00 │ 13.416666666666666 │
│ 2023-03-09 21:02:00 │    16 │ 2023-03-09 21:00:00 │ 13.785714285714286 │
│ 2023-03-10 21:00:00 │    18 │ 2023-03-10 21:00:00 │            14.3125 │
│ 2023-03-10 21:01:00 │    20 │ 2023-03-10 21:00:00 │ 14.944444444444445 │
│ 2023-03-10 21:02:00 │    22 │ 2023-03-10 21:00:00 │              15.65 │
│ 2023-03-11 21:00:00 │    23 │ 2023-03-11 21:00:00 │ 16.318181818181817 │
│ 2023-03-11 21:01:00 │    24 │ 2023-03-11 21:00:00 │ 16.958333333333332 │
│ 2023-03-11 21:02:00 │    25 │ 2023-03-11 21:00:00 │ 17.576923076923077 │
│ 2023-03-12 21:00:00 │    26 │ 2023-03-12 21:00:00 │ 18.178571428571427 │
│ 2023-03-12 21:01:00 │    27 │ 2023-03-12 21:00:00 │ 18.766666666666666 │
│ 2023-03-12 21:02:00 │    28 │ 2023-03-12 21:00:00 │           19.34375 │
│ 2023-03-13 21:00:00 │    29 │ 2023-03-13 21:00:00 │  19.91176470588235 │
│ 2023-03-13 21:01:00 │    30 │ 2023-03-13 21:00:00 │  21.08823529411765 │
│ 2023-03-13 21:02:00 │    31 │ 2023-03-13 21:00:00 │ 22.205882352941178 │
│ 2023-03-14 21:00:00 │    32 │ 2023-03-14 21:00:00 │           23.78125 │
│ 2023-03-14 21:01:00 │    33 │ 2023-03-14 21:00:00 │           24.90625 │
│ 2023-03-14 21:02:00 │    34 │ 2023-03-14 21:00:00 │             26.125 │
│ 2023-03-15 21:00:00 │    35 │ 2023-03-15 21:00:00 │            27.3125 │
│ 2023-03-15 21:01:00 │    36 │ 2023-03-15 21:00:00 │            28.4375 │
│ 2023-03-15 21:02:00 │    37 │ 2023-03-15 21:00:00 │               29.5 │
└─────────────────────┴───────┴─────────────────────┴────────────────────┘

25 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.003 sec.
```